# Get JSON response using jQuery.ajax request to an appengine URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, google-app-engine

I tried to get response data using ajax from the below url

http://recipesid.appspot.com/api.user?method=user.query&email=dam.le@anttek.com

But it will not run anyway.

Help me to solve the issue

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET", //rest Type
        dataType: 'jsonp', //mispelled
        url: "http://recipesid.appspot.com/api.user?method=user.query&email=dam.le@anttek.com",
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);                
        },
        error:
    function(data){ 
        alert("error");
    } });
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: What do you mean "cannot run anyway"? Need to say what you're expecting, what happened instead, exactly what error/debug information you have!!

Comment: that mean it always return error.

Comment: Do you want to tell us what the error is?

Comment: when i using https://www.hurl.it/ to tesing my url. 

Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,p=0
Content-Length: 213
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 24 Jun 2015 04:29:21 GMT
Server: Google Frontend

and return true result

Comment: i'm create this app in google app engine using java.

Comment: That doesn't look like an error? What is the error message?!?!

Comment: "return error" that mean it always call function error in method above.

Comment: Fair enough. But what *is* the error? The function is called for a reason.

Comment: i dont know. but when i do the same with this url http://json-cricket.appspot.com/score.json. it will run.

Comment: Well, the reason for the error is passed to the function. Maybe look at the values of the arguments?

Comment: i tried url: "/api.user?method=user.query&email=dam.le@anttek.com",
 inside my google app engine. it will run. but outside it canot run

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers. but i got a solution.

I must allow "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in my google app engine.

Comment: That error *is* obviously show up in the browser console log.